# Getting the rank of a record using two where clauses

Tags: mysql, where-clause

I am trying to get the rank of specified record, and I have some success with this code:

```
SELECT `rank`
FROM
   (
     select @rownum:=@rownum+1 `rank`, p.* 
     from TableName  p, (SELECT @rownum:=0) r 
     order by point DESC
   ) s
   WHERE names = 'house'
```

([See the schema here.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4e5155/7))

This SQL query works, but if I want to get the result according to `city_id` and `name`, I must use two `where` clauses, and then the code doesn't work.

I want to get rank of `house` only for its city. How can I do this?

Comment: What do you mean by two `where` clauses?  Please edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to get rank of "house" only for its city

You can do this by introducing another variable to keep track of the city:

```
SELECT `rank`
FROM (select p.*,
             (@rn := if(@c = city, @rn + 1,
                        if(@c := city, 1, 1)
                       )
             ) as rank
      from TableName  p CROSS JOIN
           (SELECT @rn := 0, @c := -1) params
      order by city_id, point DESC
     ) s
 WHERE names = 'house' ;
```

You can also use your original query, with a tweak, if you know that "house" only appears once in the data:

```
SELECT `rank`
FROM (select p.*, (@rn := @rn + 1) as rank
      from TableName  p CROSS JOIN
           (SELECT @rn := 0) params
      where city_id = (select city_id from TableName t2 where t2.names = 'house')
      order by point DESC
     ) s
 WHERE names = 'house' ;
```